# How should I perform rolling mean in pandas for each value of another categorical variable?

Tags: pandas

The following for loop is running very slow, but it has the gist of what I am trying to do. 
For each value of the variable "category", I would like to calculate a moving average of column 'y_all_reg' of all rows before the current row (excluding the current row). The computed value is named 'encoded' in the code copied below.

How should I do this with vectorized operations in Pandas?

```
df['encoded'] = 0 # df is already sorted by 'datetime'
categories = df['category'].unique()
for r in categories:
    subdf = df.loc[df.category == r, 'y_all_reg']
    df.loc[df.category == r, 'encoded'] = \
            subdf.expanding().mean() - subdf / subdf.expanding().count()
```

Comment: You are looking for groupby

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want `expanding().mean()` and `shift()`:

```
df['y_all_reg'] = df.groupby('category')['y_all_reg'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift())
```

**Option 2**: You could also do `expanding().mean()` and `shift()` separately:

```
g = df.groupby('category')
df['encoded'] = g['y_all_reg'].expanding().mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df['encoded'] = g['encoded'].shift()
```

**Option 3**: with a larger dataset and category counts, you can compute the rolling mean by hand:

```
g = df.groupby('category')
s = g['y_all_reg'].agg(['cumsum','cumcount'])
df['encoded'] = s['cumsum']/s['cumcount'].add(1)
df['encoded'] = g['encoded'].shift()
```

**Data:**

```
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': np.random.randint(0,2,10),
                   'encoded': np.random.uniform(0,1,10)})
```

**Output:**

```
   category  y_all_reg      encoded
0         1  0.092339           NaN
1         1  0.186260      0.092339
2         0  0.345561           NaN
3         0  0.396767      0.345561
4         1  0.538817      0.139299
5         1  0.419195      0.272472
6         1  0.685220      0.309153
7         1  0.204452      0.384366
8         1  0.878117      0.354380
9         0  0.027388      0.371164
```

**Performance:** tested on `10000` rows with `10` categories:

```
Option 1: 7.81 ms ± 98.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)    
Option 2: 8.13 ms ± 248 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
Option 3: 5.96 ms ± 261 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: My intention is that 'encoded' is initialized to 0 and later set as the rolling average of y_all_reg under its category. Not sure if yours does the same.

Comment: Yes, it does. You only need to `fillna` afterwards.

Comment: Looking at your option 1. Since encoded is initialized to 0, doesnt df.groupby('category')['encoded'].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift())  produce zero for every row?

Comment: I got the column names messed up. See the updated columns.